# Is it possible to integrate non UWP (ARM + x86) with UWP plugins?

Tags: uwp, windows-10

I hope this is a right place to ask this kind of question:

1) I have **not** Universal Windows Platform application that supports ARM and x86 architectures **only**.

2) I have SDK plugin (`.winmd` file) that built and compiled  as UWP a.e. for Windows10.

Following this Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide

> Windows 10 introduces the Universal Windows Platform (UWP), which provides a common app platform available on every device that runs Windows 10. The UWP provides a guaranteed core API across devices. This means you can create a single app package that can be installed onto a wide range of devices. And, with that single app package, the Windows Store provides a unified distribution channel to reach all the device types your app can run on. Apps that target the UWP can call not only the WinRT APIs that are common to all devices, but also APIs (including Win32 and .NET APIs) that are specific to the class of device that the app is running on.

As I understand it will work only on Window 10. And my app as non WUP will not work with plugin. Is it true?

Comment: Did you try using it? https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-winrt-apis-from-desktop-applications and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973459.aspx edit: and yes, WinRT/UWP subsystem exists only since Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly, you are asking if a portable library targeted for Windows 10 can be consumed by Windows application that is built with another technology, for example .NET.

The answer is yes.  For example a WPF application can load and execute portable libraries.  The reverse is not true.  A UWP application has to be UWP all the way down.